# Swift Inject Javascript to remove HTML element into WebView

Tags: swift, webkit, wkwebview

I am trying to inject my self directly into the source code.

We want to execute this script to remove a banner on google.com by injecting the javascript into the webview, but it's not working.

This is block of code we are trying to remove:

```
<mobile-promo jsname="EfADOe" jscontroller="sqHuef" jsaction="rcuQ6b:npT2md"> </mobile-promo>
```

This is what is not working:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    let removeGoogleBottomBar = """
        function removeDummy() {
            var elem = document.getElementById('mobile-promo');
            elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
            return false;
        }
        removeDummy()
    """
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(removeGoogleBottomBar)
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this approach to injecting javascript?

Comment: I assume it is too early, try to make it in `webView(_ , didFinish`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your javascript code will never work because you are trying to retrieve the element with id `mobile-promo`, but instead the tag name of your element is `mobile-promo`. (and it doesn't have id attribute)

If there is only one HTML element with `mobile-promo` as tag, then the following javascript code will work:

```js
function removeDummy() {
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('mobile-promo')[0];
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    return false;
}
removeDummy()
```

If not then you should do something like this:

```js
function removeDummy() {
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('mobile-promo');
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        if (elem[i].getAttribute("jsname") == "EfADOe" && elem[i].getAttribute("jscontroller") == "sqHuef" && elem[i].getAttribute("jsaction") == "rcuQ6b:npT2md") {
            elem[i].parentNode.removeChild(elem[i]);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
removeDummy()
```

To inject your javascript code, there is [WKUserScript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuserscript) API available from iOS 8. You can do something like this at `viewDidLoad`:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let source = """
    function removeDummy() {
        var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('mobile-promo')[0];
        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
        return false;
    }
    removeDummy()
    """
    let script = WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: false)
    webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
}
```

Note that just to be safe, we passing [.atDocumentEnd](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuserscriptinjectiontime/atdocumentend) as `injectionTime` parameter. As documentation states:

> Inject the script after the document finishes loading, but before
> other subresources finish loading.